# Is there any way to verify that OSX 10.8.1 installed correctly?

Tags: macos

When I was installing OSX 10.8.1, when the install when to reboot Finder refused to shut down citing a mount point problem.  I force closed Finder at which point the post-reboot install started without the system having fully rebooted.  Is there anyway to verify that nothing went wrong with the install?

Comment: Did you [re-download the update](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1571) and just run the installer to see if it completes? This usually works to clear up an interrupted installation without needing to erase and start over from a backup after installing the OS cleanly.

Comment: It's surprising to see that Apple has gotten rid of Combo Updaters. I was going to use that in my answer until I noticed I couldn't find one...

Comment: I re-downloaded it from http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1571 and reinstalled.  Seemed to clean up some glitches I was seeing.

Answer (score 1):

There is not really an easy way to verify the update went successfully. Your next steps should be to check your start up disk and then run a stand alone installer for the suspect OS X update. There is no harm in re-running an OS X installer over an OS with the same version.

1. Run Disk Utility on your start-up disk selecting Verify the Disk and also try Verify Permissions, selecting the repair options as needed.
2. Download the standalone [OS X 10.8.1 installer](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1571).
3. Re-run the installer, and hopefully this time it completes without issue.

Answer (score 0):

There really is no way to verify these things except to trust Apple to get it right. If "check for updates" doesn't tell you to update, then you should assume it worked perfectly.

From the sounds of it, you've got nothing to worry about. It takes more than finder failing to shut down to kill a software update. Most likely the update simply paused, and then automatically resumed once you force quit finder.

If you're worried, you could reboot and check for updates again.

Answer (score 0):

Yes - you can look over the install log and you could also re-download the combo updater and run it with the log file open and logging everything.

Both will alert you if there are problems deploying the patch.